# Given a specific regular expression, how I can make the search stop if a certain word is reached?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that finds whole words in a string (matching a user's search query), but I would like to ignore everything after a certain word is reached.

Imagine the following list of possible search results:

- Foo (see Foo Bar)
- Bar (see Foo Bar)
- Foo Bar

I want to use the regular expression to test each item in the list, and I want to ignore everything after the word "see". For example:

- If the users searches for "foo", I would like to match the first and third items:

  - **Foo** (see Foo Bar)
  - Bar (see Foo Bar)
  - **Foo** Bar
- If the user searches for "bar", I would like to match the second and third items:

  - Foo (see Foo Bar)
  - **Bar** (see Foo Bar)
  - Foo **Bar**

The regular expression I came up with is this:

```
^(?!\(see)(\b%SEARCH%)
```

...where `%SEARCH%` gets replaced with whatever the search term is.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in all cases. It seems to correctly match items if the search term is at the beginning of the string (i.e., "foo"), but not if the search term appears later in the string (i.e., "bar" in the third item in the list).

Here's a [jsfiddle that illustrates the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/9cud5/). Everything works as expected in the first and third examples, but in the second example, the third item ("Foo Bar") should also be matched but it isn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Notes:

- I want to match whole words only, hence the `\b`
- I'm also using the `i` modifier (for case insensitivity) and `g` modifier (to find all matches).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not offering you a fully working code but here is how I would approach this problem.

Rather that trying to find a complex regex to avoid search after `(see...)` it is better to do it in 2 steps:

1. Find sub-string before *optional* `(see...)`
2. In the sub-string find and highlight your search term